# Kashering a kashering pot

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization

My family, after boiling water and pouring it into the sink to kasher the sink, then reboils that pot and causes it to overflow in effect kashering itself. 
Is there any source to be required to do this or did my parents (balei teshuvah) just misunderstand something they were taught?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%91_%D7%90

Comment: Not sure what this comment is supposed to say.  Does it answer the question. Anyway the correct way to do it is to heat up a brick (part of one) not a stone and pour hot water from a kettle onto it, holding the brick with a pliers all over the sink. Not sure why should you use a pot and not an electric kettle.

Comment: If I recall correctly the hot brick is only required if the vessel you are kashering comes into direct contact with a kli rishon. In my particular scenario it only gets iruy kli rishon and so to kasher it you only need iruy